# requirejs - fail to load module using relative path

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

In my project, I have a js folder with multiple files. 
One file under the js folder, app.js, is dependent on other files also under that folder.

I read here ([Relative module names inside define()](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes)) that if you use a "local require" you can load modules using relative paths. So for example if I have:

```
js
|- app.js
|- util.js
|- logger.js
```

Then I can do:

```
//in app.js
define(function(require){
 var util = require("./util");
 var logger = require("./logger");    
 ...
});
```

But for some reason this isn't working for me. What I do see happening is that the modules util & logger are being requested relative to the baseUrl I defined in my require configuration.

This is not what I expected to happen and I can't really understand why it does, especially because I have other modules in my project that do work correctly with the relative paths.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

Is it possible that this happens here because I am loading app.js from another module using the global require?

In init.js I have:

```
//in init.js
require(["config"], function (config) {
    require(["app"], function (app) {
    });
});
```

Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1st. Try to avoid CommonJS style calls to `require` Go for AMD style.

CommonJS style:

```
var result = require(resource)
```

AMD style:

```
require([resource], function(result){})
```

RequireJS does **NOT** do sync loading of CJS style resources. It emulates it by inspecting the body of the function and injecting requirements into define. You don't see it, but what you wrote there is actually ran as:

```
// app.js
define(['require', 'exports', 'module', './util', './logger'], function(require){
    var util = require("./util"); // <- "sync" call is ok because it's pre-loaded
    var logger = require("./logger"); // <- "sync" call is ok because it's pre-
});
```

You are entering the voodoo territory there. Try to be explicit about things you need instead:

```
// app.js
define(['./util', './logger'], function(util, logger){
    ...
});
```

But if you really want to play with "local" require, do it in AMD way as it for sure kicks in all the module ID resolution rules:

```
// app.js
define(['require'], function(require){
    require(
        ['./util', './logger']
        , function(util, logger){
            ...
        }
    )
});
```

Also, this part does not make sense to me:

```
require(["config"], function (config) {
    require(["app"], function (app) {
    });
});
```

I would expect `"app"` to be `"js/app"` What's the value of `baseUrl` - `'js'`?

The paths in app.js define look right, but the way RequireJS resolves `"app"` may be a problem.